# Load grammar at runtime

Tags: c++, parsing, dynamic, runtime, grammar

I'm coding a project in C++, and I'm looking for a way to put in a text file ( usergrammar.txt ), in a humanly readable/writable form, a user-defined grammar which defines objects.

Once done this I'd like to be able to instance some of those objects in the code, and save the created instances in another file ( instances.txt ), always in humanly accessible format. This second file is obviously dependent on the first to be read correctly.

What I'm having trouble with is how to define the grammars and parsing them. I've been looking at Boost::Spirit, but while it would do a good job on reading the first file ( since its rules are predefined ), I don't think it is applicable to the second one since Spirit grammars are only defined a compile time and cannot be loaded at runtime ( at least that's what I understood ).

Now I'm reading about the ENBF form, but I also have the problem that I not only have the language rules, but that each object has a particular and different name/description/options every time its included in another one ( For example, if I have the object colour, the integers inside it would be called red, blue, yello, while if the object is ruler, its integer would be called length ), so I have a way to include these informations into the file as well, and getting them to be associated with the corrisponding values correctly.

Do you have any pointers to what to look/study/use/do for a project like this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the general format that you have in mind? Would using XML work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to having some restrictions on the format of your files, you could look into using XML or JSON to describe your grammars.

You could have a grammar file that looks like

```
{
    "ObjectTypes" : {
        "ruler" : { "properties" : [ "length" ] },
        "color" : { "properties" : [ "red", "green", "blue" ] }
    }
}
```

After reading in this file (using some pre-existing library, most likely), you could then read in another file that would have your actual objects. It could look something like this:

```
{
    "Objects" : [
        { name : "object1", "type" : "ruler", "length" : 5 },
        { name : "object2", "type" : "color", "red" : 5, "blue" : 127, "green" : 150, }
    ]
}
```

And so forth. A more descriptive overview of JSON is given [here](http://json.org), which includes links to several C++ libraries that handle JSON (My personal favorite is [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: I've tried to use JSON and XML, but as far as I understood they don't support optional parameters, or interchangeable parameters ( this OR that ). Also you can't use a defined object inside of another one.For example:
`Object1:
 Item1:
  Type:
   Number
  Description:
   First description
  Option:
   Option1
   Option2
 Item2:
  Type:
   Object2
  Description:
   Second description
 Item3:
  Type:
   Object3
  Description:
   Second description
  
Object1 Composition:
 Optional( Item1 ) + ( Item2 OR Item3 )`
And so on. If I failed to see how to do it I'll happily try again.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough characters to edit that better, but I hope the content is understandable. @Datalore

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Optional parameters" or "Interchangable parameters"; you can have arbitrary key/value pairs inside JSON objects and arbitrary lists inside JSON arrays (mutually nested at will). You can read from one JSON object some sort of specification, and then use that specification to direct your c++ program in reading another set of JSON objects and doing something with them.

Comment: I was referring to the actual grammar. The objects are composed of items, but these may be optional or an item's type could be chosen between different options. However I realize I'll probably have to save the grammar in a custom format within the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

See [Earley parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) which parse context free langauges using facts extracted from a grammar provided at runtime.

An alternative is to use the fact that virtually all C++ compiler systems provide libraries that can fork a process.   You can use that to fork a shell script to run any parser generator scheme you like (including Boost:Spirit, requiring to you call the C++ compiler from the script but that's not hard) based on any corresponding grammar formalism, and then have that script invoke the generated parser.    If you have large documents to process, this will likely be more efficient than the Earley parser.   It will certainly be a lot easier to implement.

Comment: Your forking solution looks rather unportable, unfortunately ( I may be wrong though ). I'll be sure to look at Earley parsers, thanks for the link!

Comment: Depends on where you port to.  Flex/Bison are widely available, and fork is fairly standard primitive.